# Explode php array endpoint

Tags: php, arrays, api, symfony, explode

Need some help exploding this PHP array and assign it a variable to each.

in Splits i have two inputs.  a first name and last name.
example.

Chris Moreno.   I want to be able to grab that and endpoint and exploding it and pass them into a variable.

> (endpoint) api.org/endpoint?filter= Chris Moreno

```
$splits = explode(' ', $filter);

foreach ( $splits as $key => $literalFilter){}

fName = chris
lName = moreno
```

Ive tried a could of things but i am not able to do it.  has someone ran into this before?

if i do vardump at $splits i get the following;

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "chloe"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "moreno"
}
```

Comment: I'll give you half the answer: `$fname = $splits[ 0 ];`

Comment: I am already using the variable $filter to do that.  ($filter = $request->get('filter');).   when i do that alone I get "Chris Moreno" as one string.   My ultimate goal is to be able to split them so i can allow users to search by first and last name via a msyql query.

Comment: wait, did I misunderstand the question entirely? (based on last comment in chain)

Comment: @treyBake no, your right on the money, I think i just fazed out that i couldn't see that.  I like the list as well.   Thank you.  do you know Doctrine fairly well?  my next step to do a doctrine query so that i can search by first and last name now that i have those endpoints in variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

> list — Assign variables as if they were an array

example with your code:

```
list($first, $last) = explode(' ', $filter);
```

Essentially, you list out varnames for the array indexes to follow, so if you had an array of:

> Array => [1, 4, 5];

you could do:

```
list($foo, $bar, $foobar) = $array;
echo $foo. ' ' .$bar. ' '.$foobar; # will output 1 4 5
```

full docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php